# Do I need to create an iOS Development Certificate for each iOS Development team that I'm a part of?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I have been developing iPhone apps as part of an iOS development team for quite a while.

Just recently I've been developing an app for a client who wants this app submitted into iTunes under their development account. Thus, I joined their development team.

My question is: do I now have to create a new iOS Development Certificate for myself under this new team?

When I go into my account (and have selected my new team), there aren't any development certificates. My role is a team admin (for the new team).

Answer (score 0):

For your own development, it doesn't matter as much. It depends most on what provisioning profiles you have (if you'll be able to sign and run the app on your own device using the certs/profiles from the other team). Obviously, though, when it comes time to submit to the App Store, you'll have to be using the correct certificates and such.

Comment: Thanks. I mainly just need to use the new team's Distribution certificate (which can only be created by the Team Agent, right?), so I guess I don't really need to worry about it right now?

Comment: Yeah. The point of the development stuff is for you to be able to test it yourself. If you can get that working using the "wrong" certs, it doesn't matter. It does matter for distribution (esp. App Store).